# Wordpress - Disabling automated resizing system

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I'm having this problem with Wordpress image resizing system.
Started getting this after upgraded to 4.2.2.

I use one page responsive theme and there's photo gallery on the portfolio part. when you click one of thumbnail then Ajax load to show bigger photos, not with the lightbox.

This is the same theme I use:
http://visia.themes.pixelentity.com

(Click "FOLIO" to go to "OUR WORK" section, then click one of thumbnails to open up bigger images. This bigger image part was called "Project" in the admin area, those thumbnails are coming from "Galleries", "OUR WORK" section was made from "Page" in the admin.)
But on my site, after you upload photos on the gallery, it generates the specific size of the window, presumably code in php somewhere in my theme folder.

and if you check the source code,

```
<img alt="" width="680" height="519" src="http://YOURDOMAIN.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/YOURPHOTO-680x519.jpg">
```

It adds "680x519" at the end of image url taken from Media upload folder.

But if you see the original theme site, the photos shows perfectly, but not my site. (Before the upgrade, shows perfectly.)

I have tried some suggestions from multiple forums but they only removes size attributes using these add_filer codes below attached into function.php:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );

function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}
```

But no luck.

As I'm a designer, not a developer, honestly don't not how it works.
Hoping anyone knows how to remove size dimension code automatically added into uploaded images in my gallery.

Comment: So if I understand you problem, when you upload an image it hardcodes a size (likely based on the actual size of the image) which makes the image size unresponsive?  What you could do is use CSS Media Queries to either change the width in pixels, or to use percentages to adjust the images dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes it does hardcode a size. it resizes it and changes the path of the image url, which does not actually exist. Thus the image is not showing up. I checked the upload folder inside of wp-content, and there is however the image file named with 680x519 added the end of the original file, but it actually contains nothing, zero kb. It generate the resized image but not completely. I just wanted to stop this auto resizing.

Comment: If the image is empty it seems like there is a problem with the WordPress uploaded you may want to report that as a bug.  The auto resizing you would have to change somewhere in the wp-admin php files I would think.  But you could upload the files via FTP and size them appropriately with CSS to get around the whole WordPress mess lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the bastard that caused this problem.

As it was only happened to a specific photos, in this case, on my gallery photos.
So I looked for a gallery php file in my theme folder and there was this file called MYTHEME-gallery.php.

Then I found this line:

```
$destfilename = "{$upload_dir}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
```

and removed -{$suffix}

Voilà! the hardcoded url disappeared and images showed up.